# Match Routing Google maps android

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

I need to find out if 2 people are taking the same route to travel from point A to point B. Google maps returns multiple routes to travel from point A to point B. I am allowing users to mark waypoints to select a particular route. But in some cases, even if the routes are the same, if the selected waypoint is not present in the route array it does not match the same route. Is waypoints the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deal with this situation is to set the ***alternatives*** parameter to ***false***. This would specify the direction services to just set one route for point A and B. Setting up waypoints may be a hassle for the users if they want to get the same route everytime.

More details can be found in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters).

Comment: I don't think thats what he meant, he is asking if there is a way to match people at certain locations nearby a route